# Location with High Salvagable Materials Drop Rate

Tags: guild-wars-2

So with the February Monthly Achievement; we need to salvage 500 items.  This comes out to roughly 18 per day (assuming you play every day this month); but for the sake of argument lets say I want to salvage 25 items per day.

What areas have mobs that will drop salvageable items at an acceptable rate?

Ideally; I'd think you'd want enemies that would typically drop armor/weapons.  Ones that drop rare crafting materials (while helpful) seems to be less important.  Also; it seems like you'd want to avoid enemies that drop bags (as you get no salvage points for them).

My assumption is that I'd want to run dungeons a bunch of times (3 fractals seem to fill up a good chunk of my inventory) as well as areas with lots of humanoid enemies (pirate/bandit camps)

Another viable strategy seems to be spinning up a new alt and ranking up my crafting skill and then salvaging the created items.  (Currently my main is an ele with Tailor/Artificer; so fire up a ranger with Leatherworking/Huntsman)

Comment: I'd say specifically farming for salvagable items to do your monthly is probably just wasting time. Generally speaking this one should just come naturally from playing. Just do what you'd normally do and you'll have plenty to salvage!

Comment: You can actually swap out professions on the one character - you can relearn a previous profession (for a fee) with no loss of skill.

Comment: I don't really know where you can find the perfect salvageable-drop monster, but seeing my progression in the salvage percentage I guess the achievement is balanced so with your standard playing you should get it.
Otherwise, if you run out of time on the last days you can always buy the cheaper items from vendors or trading post (as David B suggested) and it should do the trick!

Comment: I'm finding this easy by just playing normally. I'm salvaging all my white and blue items.

Comment: I got this achievement just by salvaging items I constructed while levelling professions

Comment: Just to follow up; I spent some time last night and found that Fireheart Rise seems to be a decent area.  There's several events (take back the beach, reclaim the quarry, etc.) that have lots of Fire Legion.  Also found that the TP seems to have adjusted for the monthly achievement; some rares are actually cheaper than commons.  Ended up buying around 150 cheap items to catch up my current pace.  Looks like my winning strategy will be to work on my map completion/dungeon requirement; and then supplement with TP purchases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I aquire 500 salvage-able items with minimal effort or cost?

Right now there are [Malachite Copper Rings](http://www.gw2spidy.com/item/13271) available for 31 copper each (58k of them).  These are just the first item I found and may not be the cheapest possibility.

If you bought 500 of these, it would cost 1g55s.  If you salvaged them (using cheap honor kits) and only got 500 copper ore, you would recoup 70s at immediate sale prices.  That would net out to 85s cost.